# How to unclog or flush a toilet that when plunged it pushes up the overflow tube?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, plumbing-fixture, clog

I have a clogged toilet in an apartment and every time I try to plunge it with my plunger it pushes up the overflow tube(?). I've tried plunging it less and more forcefully but both just push up the overflow tube.

If it helps, I might have an airlock in my toilet as before the clog it would send up a bubble after it was flushed. I don't know if the siphon jet is clogged or not so that might be it.

Comment: block that tube while you do your thing. plastic bag and duct tape work well.

Comment: @dandavis Do you mean to hold it down or to cover it up?

Comment: A wet rag also works to cover overflow tube and allow the suction to do its thing,.  You can hold it in place with one hand and plunge with the other.  Or team up with an assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it takes more force and more volume.  The type of plunger with the plastic bellows would help if you can get one.  If the bowl has drained, it helps to put more water in the bowl to add some pressure.

If it's still clogged after several plunger attempts, I would get a toilet snake and try to break up the clog.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but but no matter hard or how many times it either keeps pushing up the overflow tube, shoots water up through the overflow tube, or it even flushed the toilet. Do I any hope?

Comment: That sounds frustrating.  Next step is to try to snake it.  I added that above.

Comment: I bought a drain snake for $15. I could have bought one for $10 but it wasn't available. Toilet snake is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The next device beyond a plunger, is a snake designed for toilets. It's called a "closet auger"   You can usually buy or rent them at the home rental places, including Home Depot.

The feature is that it consists of a plastic or rubber coated sheath that lets you get the large metal snake into the back of the toilet bowl without scratching the finish.

[HD Toilet Auger](https://www.homedepot.com/p/rental/Electric-Eel-Mfg-Co-Inc-and-General-Wire-Spring-Toilet-Auger-CA-3A/310643025)

Comment: You can purchase the closet auger for less than a day's rental (based on prices at your provided link), and it's handy to have stashed in the garage or other storage area if you happen need it at midnight...

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't my observation last I looked, but every market is different.  Fortunately I do own one, but my Mother does not.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to clear a blockage with a plunger is to gently push the plunger down and then vigorously pull it up. This creates a suction which loosens the blockage.

**EDIT
It should not be necessary to stuff a wet rag into the overflow tube.  This should have nothing to do with the suction on the blockage. When I plunge a toilet I never try to plug the overflow tube. I never even take the lid off the tank. AFIK the overflow tube is connected only to the openings around the top of the rim.**

Comment: I tried this, put a wet cloth over the overflow tube then gently at first pushed the plunger as far it could go then yanked it out but the problem is that there's a tube that goes down the middle of the overflow tube so I couldn't really completely cover it and I either couldn't couldn't get a good suction or it didn't work.

Comment: When I plunge a toilet I never try to plug the overflow tube. I never take the lid off the tank. AFIK the overflow tube is connected only to the openings around the top of the rim.